# Kubernetes: The PersistentVolume is invalid: and spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: is immutable after creation

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to patch the PV with new volume id,

```
kubectl patch pv pvname -p '{"spec":{"awsElasticBlockStore":{"volumeID":"aws://eu-central-1c/volumeid"}}}'
```

But getting below error:

> The persistentvolume pvname is invalid:  spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: spec.persistentvolumesource is immutable after creation

how to proceed?

Comment: Can you add your yml file?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message, "spec.persistentvolumesource is immutable after creation", means you *can't* change the volume ID attached to a PersistentVolume.  If you're manually creating PVs (normally you wouldn't) you need to create a new one with a different name.

Several other objects in Kubernetes are immutable, with the most notable example being Pods.  You similarly can't change a Pod's image once it's been created, you need to destroy the existing Pod and create a new one.  Normally you work with a higher-level mutable object like a Deployment that knows how to do this on its own.